# Receive day id to use in where clause (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to make a SQL Server query like this:

```
Select * 
From table 
Where GetDayOfWeekId(DateColumn) = 1
```

`DateColumn` has a string value like `2014-04-18`

Is there a function that can extract a day name or an id to use in the where clause?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * From table Where DATENAME(dw,DateColumn) = 'Monday'
Select * From table Where DATEPART(dw,DateColumn) = 1
```

[**More DATE info extracting Functions**](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2507/determine-sql-server-date-and-time-with-datepart-and-datename-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand you need:

```
Select * From table Where DATEPART(weekday,DateColumn) = 1
```